# Who can better explain what this snippet of code does line by line

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to understand this snippet of code and I have totally failed to understand. Explanation on how `math.Max()` is able to find the height of a tree

```
  /**
   * @return {number}
   */
  get leftHeight() {
    if (!this.left) {
      return 0;
    }

    return this.left.height + 1;
  }

  /**
   * @return {number}
   */
  get rightHeight() {
    if (!this.right) {
      return 0;
    }

    return this.right.height + 1;
  }

  /**
   * @return {number}
   */
  get height() {
    return Math.max(this.leftHeight, this.rightHeight);
  }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: You should post the whole code, at least the `class` around this and its `constructor` so that we see how your binary trees are defined.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get - the above is just a series of getters culminating in the last one which returns the max value from the two previous - looking at it, it's probably  trying to equalise the height of two columns as the last getter returns the max height of the two elements left and right

Comment: Is it about the particular syntax, or do you have problems with the algorithm of computing the height?

Comment: "*I can't seem to understand it better*" - please explain in detail what you *do* understand about each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get leftHeight()` and `get rightHeight()` are recursive, as they call themselves. `get leftHeight()` will return how many times you can go left from a given node, and `get rightHeight()` will return how many times you can go right from a given node. `get height()` will return whichever one is the largest, which is not actually the height of the node.

For example:
[image]

The `.height` of the top `2` node in this tree will be the max of going left continuously: 2 (2, 7, 2) and going right continuously: 2 (2, 5, 9), returning 2.

To get the actual height of this node, you would want to return `.height` for each node in the recursion, so the max height will be returned at every recursion.

The recursion in the `get leftHeight()` and `get rightHeight()` stops when `(!this.left)` or `(!this.right)` is true, respectively, which is just checking if it is undefined and the node does not have a left or right node respectively.